# Running my function only when a class has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to only run my function once my class "button" has loaded on the page, and also detect that the page has changed, no console errors but "i'm in start" is never returned.

```
   window.addEventListener ("load", start);
    function Start() {
       console.log("i'm in start");
       var OldHtml = window.jQuery.fn.html;

       window.jQuery.fn.html = function () {

         var EnhancedHtml = OldHtml.apply(this, arguments);

         if (arguments.length && EnhancedHtml.find("button").length) {

             var TheElementAdded = EnhancedHtml.find("button"); //there it is
         }

         return EnhancedHtml;
       }
    }

    $(myfunction,false);
```

Expected Result: "I'm in start" to be console logged

Actual result: "I'm in start" not logged, function not run with no console errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might just need to capitalize Start on the event listener.

```
    window.addEventListener ("load", Start);
```

Another option, if you don't need to call start again.

```
    window.addEventListener ("load",
    function() {
       console.log("i'm in start");
       var OldHtml = window.jQuery.fn.html;

       window.jQuery.fn.html = function () {

         var EnhancedHtml = OldHtml.apply(this, arguments);

         if (arguments.length && EnhancedHtml.find("button").length) {

             var TheElementAdded = EnhancedHtml.find("button"); //there it is
         }

         return EnhancedHtml;
       }
    });
```